# javascript css change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code should be fairly simple but im not sure why its not working its making me go insane. It should just get the clock id and then just change its background dynamically based on the time.
The code i have is

```
init();
function init(){
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
if(datetime==1||datetime==13){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock1.png)";
}
else if(datetime==2||datetime==14){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock2.png)";
}
else if(datetime==3||datetime==15){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock3.png)";
}
else if(datetime==4||datetime==16){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock4.png)";
}
else if(datetime==5||datetime==17){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock5.png)";
}
else if(datetime==6||datetime==18){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock6.png)";
}
else if(datetime==7||datetime==19){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock7.png)";
}
else if(datetime==8||datetime==20){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock8.png)";
}
else if(datetime==9||datetime==21){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock9.png)";
}
else if(datetime==10||datetime==22){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock10.png)";
}
else if(datetime==11||datetime==23){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock11.png)";
}
else if(datetime==0||datetime==12){
clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock12.png)";
}
}
```

and the HTML is

```
<div id="clock"><img src="clock/pill.png" alt="pill image" id="pillpic"/></div>
```

Comment: What's happening that is not correct? What are the symptoms? Use the Dev Console or something to check the background of the div. Is the background image value changing? Is the image not found?

Comment: Not too familiar with setting css using javascript but you could try setting the `css` with jQuery instead.  `$(clock).css('background-image','url(clock/clock1.png)')`  Are all your if statements getting executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work fine as long as it's running *after* the `clock` element has loaded. Be sure to put your script below that element, or use an event handler that runs after the DOM is loaded.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code.

```
init();

function init() {
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    var t = (new Date().getHours() % 12) || 12;

    clock.style.backgroundImage = "url(clock/clock" + t + ".png)";
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/EnN6s/

Also make sure your image path is correct.

Comment: perfect, it works now with your code and probably mine too, yours is just a lot neater! I was just calling init(); in the wrong place. cheers

Comment: @user2232418: Ah, yeah that'll do it! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function init(){
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
    datetime = datetime >= 12 ? datetime-12 : datetime;
    clock.style.backgroundImage="url(clock/clock"+datetime+".png)";
}
init();
```